# Is Content-MD5 field in the HTTP Response universal?

Tags: http, hash, httpwebrequest, md5

I have tried downloading files from different servers, NOT all of them respond with the Content-MD5 field in their headers.

I wanted to know if that it is the standard to HTTP response without the hash of the resource file or not?

thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> The Content-MD5 header field **MAY** be generated by an origin server or client to function as an integrity check of the entity-body. Only origin servers or clients **MAY** generate the Content-MD5 header field; proxies and gateways MUST NOT generate it, as this would defeat its value as an end-to-end integrity check. Any recipient of the entity- body, including gateways and proxies, **MAY** check that the digest value in this header field matches that of the entity-body as receive

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

As of June 2014:

> The Content-MD5 header field has been removed because it was
> inconsistently implemented with respect to partial responses.

RFC 7231 - Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Semantics and Content - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231 (page 92)

Answer (score 6):

HTTPbis is deprecating that header field (see http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/178 for details).

Answer (score 0):

Pure MD5 does not support partial verification and is obsoleted. If you try to use use pure hash functions for anything advanced, eventually you'll meet the [following situation](http://www.gnutellaforums.com/download-upload-problems/40973-file-downloads-starts-all-over-again-print.html):

> I don't get it... As soon as a file is ready to finish, it starts all
>   over again. I also get the message "Verifying File Contents"... What
>   am I to do???

What if one downloads over and over 20Gb file having no chance to detect mismatch early? One cannot offload downloads to p2p without partial verification supported by hash function.

So nowadays one needs to stick with Merkle trees. Gnutella (both G1 and G2) and DC++ (both NMDC and ADC) use TTH (TIGER Tree Hash) while eDonkey 2k use AICH, but it is alone to use this hash, and it is less elegant. So TTH is the de facto standard, and it would be nice if all file hashes everywhere (even when not strictly required) were TTH by default, but we are not there yet.

DC++ is not based on HTTP, but Gnutella (1 and 2) is, so you can study and/or support those HTTP headers. For instance, Shareaza can intercept downloads from browsers and offload them to p2p using Alt-Location, Content-URN, X-Thex-URI headers.